# Bash Script - last show numer of login session of the day

Tags: linux, bash

In what way cal I display the number of login to system of the day?
Eg.

Date, this user logins and the number of logins on a given day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this to `.bash_profile`:

```
touch .daily_login_count
read tomorrow count < .daily_login_count   # It's OK if file is empty
# Check if this is the first login of the day
if (( $(date +%s) > tomorrow )); then
    count=0
    (( tomorrow += 86400 ))
fi
(( count++ ))
echo "$tomorrow $count" > .daily_login_count
echo "$(date) $user $count login(s) today"
```